# Transfer of file from one machine to another machine

Tags: ftp, file-transfer

> There are 2 machines on a network on which GUI is not installed to save the memory. Transfer a file from 1 such machine to another similar machine.

Possible methods I think could be
1. If we can the other computer on the network, we can put the items into a "shared" folder (or making an existing one "shared').
2. Using the ftp protocol on the command line and connecting to one of the machines acting as ftp server and downloading files from that using command 'get' to download the file
3. Create a TCP connection across the two machines. One machine which is having the file will read it and write it to the socket and another one will read it from the socket.

Could there be more solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual solution is to use SCP to transfer files using a SSH connection.

Comment: But GUI is not installed on the machine. Hence it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Luv, `scp` doesn't _need_ a GUI. But I have to say that I'd question the assertion that `scp` is more prevalent than standard `FTP` without some sort of support. It _is_ another solution however.

Comment: I agree. Edited to be less assertive.